# Error when excecuting firejail from zathura: cannot create /run/firejail/profile/14844

Tags: zathura, firejail

In zathura, I use `:exec firejail firefox` to start firefox with firejail. There is an error "cannot create /run/firejail/profile/14844" and firefox does not start. When I type `firejail firefox` in terminal, it works well. I guess this may be related to privilege problem. But I do not know how. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related question: [hyperref - Zathura not opening hyperlinks - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/564989/zathura-not-opening-hyperlinks/616746#616746)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that zathura sandboxes the process, which disable the feature to create a sandbox.

See [`man zathurarc`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/zathurarc.5) for more details.

For instance, to set sandbox mode to `none`, put in `~/.config/zathurarc` this line

```
set sandbox none
```

With that `firejail firefox` should work.

Comment: The zathura bug about this: https://git.pwmt.org/pwmt/zathura/-/issues/151